# Rails: Save a User ID to the DB but only show User Name in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my "Sales"-View I want to manually assign a UserID to a "Sale".
Normally the User ID and name gets saved in the controller through

```
@sale.user_id = current_user.id
@sale.name = current_user.name
```

But I want to manually overwrite those values through something like this:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.all.map { |c| "#{[c.name]} #{[c.id]}" }, :prompt => "Choose..", class: "form-control" %>
```

But this one is trying to save the whole array to the sale.user_id column. How would you solve that problem?

**In short: The Dropdown should only show the Username but save the UserID to the DB.**

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you getting right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :name, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I made a mistake: The code seems right. But could you extend it so that it also saves the new "name"? This would give me one single drop-down that saves two records into the DB. Would that be possible?

Comment: If that is the case, why don't you fetch name in the backend and save. Saving two things from dropdown might be cumbersome. However you can do it by manipulating data. Like `name(id)` then in backend, splitting them in `name` and `id`and save.

Comment: That's the problem: The current_user.id and the current_user.name gets saved to the db within the "Sales" table. But I want to be able to manually overwrite those two values. Your code-snippet is great but it only saves the id and not the name to the db. Do you know how I get the real username from the "Users" table through the UserID from the "Sales" Table? This would solve the problem I think..

Comment: Once you have the `user_id` then you can find the name of user like this `User.find_by_id(user_id).name`

Comment: The whole thing worked now. I forgot to permit user_id inside my sales controller... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, :prompt => "Choose..", class: "form-control" %>
```